# What is print (df.head(20).to_dict()) ?How to get average of field in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame as :

```
    Year      Sex  Count
0    yob1880   F    942
1    yob1880   M   1058
2    yob1881   F    938
3    yob1881   M    997
4    yob1882   F   1028
5    yob1882   M   1099
6    yob1883   F   1054
7    yob1883   M   1030
8    yob1884   F   1172
```

I need to find the average of `Male` and `female` in each `year`as below:

Year     Sex   Count
0  yob1880   F     47.5
1  yob1880   M     52.5
 and so on...

Comment: Use `df = df.groupby(['Year', 'Sex'], as_index=False)['Count'].mean()`. Or do you need extract years from `yob1880` to integer also?

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: I have added the result also in the question part..

Comment: OK, thanks, see dupe answer. this is what you need.

Comment: I have tried your code, but igetting the same result i.e no change in my original dataframe

Comment: What is `print (df.head(20).to_dict())` ?

Comment: It will convert the dataframe to dictionary.... Do you mean this?

Comment: Yes, and please add it to question.

Comment: I think you can add output of `print (df.head(20).to_dict())` to question body, not to question title.